# Connection string for SQL Server on different router but same modem

Tags: sql, tcp, connection-string, lan

I'm pretty new to SQL Server connections and I've been having trouble trying to connect to a SQL Server on another computer when it's connected to a different router.

The connection works fine when both computers are connected to the same router, but it doesn't work when I switch the connection of one of the computers. Since both routers are connected to the same modem, is it possible to make the SQL Server connection without having to go through the internet?

PS: I'm trying to make the connection with a connection string in an application I'm developing

Comment: Are the 2 routers part of the same network or are you running two separate networks? If 2 separate networks, then have you configured them so that they can "see" each other?

Comment: Thanks for asking. I dont think theyre in the same network, and I dont believe ive configured them to see each other. How do you do that?.

 Oh by the way the 2 routers are pretty far from each other.

Comment: Setting up networks is a skilled activity so if you don't know how to do it you will probably need to pay a network engineer to do it for you

Comment: ok i see i see ty for letting me know